# The method getConnection() is undefined for the type DataSource

Tags: java, datasource

I am connecting to an oracle database using a connection pool. I have set up my datasource file but when I try to get a connection I get the error

**The method getConnection() is undefined for the type DataSource**

I have searched the internet and it doesn't seem to be a common problem. I am not sure what I have done wrong.

The code is:

```
<datasources>  
<local-tx-datasource>  
    <jndi-name>DefaultDS</jndi-name>  
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@ED.OPTO:1521:OPY>  
    <driver-class>oracle.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>  
    <user-name>temiuser</user-name>  
    <password>password</password>  
 </local-tx-datasource>
```

```
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.sql.*;


public class dataSource {

    // load the driver
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

    String sourceFile = "java:/TVEContent";
    InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
    DataSource ds = (DataSource)ic.lookup(sourceFile);
    Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
    Statement stmnt = conn.createStatement("select * from tve");
```

}

Please help!!!!

Comment: Name clash: `import javax.sql.DataSource;` **;)**

Comment: @JoopEggen: You might want to post that as an answer.

Comment: @JoopEggen, maybe you should add that as an answer? since it is the answer :)

Comment: Thanks! I put that in and took out import javax.activation.DataSource and that solved that issue but now it says: conn cannot be resolved : (

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Name clash: `import javax.sql.DataSource;`

BTW should it not be `ic.lookup("DefaultDS")` (unsure at the moment)?

Comment: Thanks! I put that in and took out import javax.activation.DataSource and that solved that issue but now it says: conn cannot be resolved : (

Comment: If the XML is taken as configuration, did you try `lookup("DefaultDS")`? The jndi-name normally is used.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seem to be this library:

import javax.activation.DataSource;

**Try this instead:**

javax.sql.DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource)ic.lookup(sourceFile);

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your driver does not match your runtime, **check that your oracle jar file matches your jdk version**

Because the error "The method getConnection() is undefined for the type DataSource" means : method getConnection() of Datasouce version "1.foo" not found. Your driver method getConnection() implements Datasource version "1.bar"