# Context.xml way for get connection

Tags: java

Im trying to make connection in my java code with the database, using context.xml file and my code is as follows,

```
 InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
    Context xmlContext = (Context) ic.lookup("java:comp/env"); 
    DataSource myDatasource = (DataSource) ((InitialContext)
xmlContext).lookup("jdbc/MyDatasource");


    con = myDatasource.getConnection();
```

But im getting error on last line (con=myDataSource.getConnection();) stating add cast to myDataSource..m not able to resolve this..any help??   My imports are as follows

```
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;


import com.lowagie.text.pdf.codec.postscript.ParseException;
```

Comment: please post your imports too.

Comment: i have posted my imports..

Answer (score 0):

I basically copy/pasted your code in Eclipse, and *leaned on the compiler* for it to suggest the imports you see. The type of `con` in my case comes from `java.sql.Connection`.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class Test {

    void doit() throws NamingException, SQLException {
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
        Context xmlContext = (Context) ic.lookup("java:comp/env");
        DataSource myDatasource = (DataSource) ((InitialContext) xmlContext)
                .lookup("jdbc/MyDatasource");

        Connection con = myDatasource.getConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats there, i have defined it same way..as u defines, but its giving me error,The method getConnection() is undefined for the type DataSource

Comment: You may have `javax.activation.DataSource` instead of `javax.sql.DataSource`. Look out for a naming clash. See here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403593/the-method-getconnection-is-undefined-for-the-type-datasource

Comment: yes i changed it, now it has that method but errors go on saying surround it with try catch, when surrounded everythn with try catch, its giving me namingexception on InitialContext line

Comment: Perhaps have a look the Oracle documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/basics/prepare/initial.html

Comment: i checked them, my .java is now errorfree after adding some throws declarations, but when i run it im getting the excpetion as

Comment: Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
 at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:645)
 at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
 at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:325)
 at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
 at modules.images.Chart.createDataset(Chart.java:376)

Comment: @user2793926 Please have a look at my answer. i think you were doing mistake while doing lookup

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will solve your problem as it is working in my case :

```
 Context ic = new InitialContext();
 DataSource myDatasource= (DataSource) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/MyDatasource");
 Connection con = myDatasource.getConnection();
```

OR the below one take from [JNDI datasource](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/2.1.x/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html)

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/MyDatasource");
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```

Comment: prateek sorry to say but m still with the same error after editing this also